# ¿Cómo domar la propagación selectiva en un escenario de botones anidados?

Tags: eventos

** Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar manejar eventos en JavaScript. Mi objetivo es evitar que un evento se propague al elemento padre cuando se hace clic en ciertos botones, utilizando el método stopPropagation(). Sin embargo, parece que esta estrategia no está funcionando como esperaba.

Adjunto está el código HTML y JavaScript que estoy utilizando para ilustrar el problema: **

```js
document.getElementById('contenedor').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Clic en el contenedor');
});

document.getElementById('boton1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Clic en el Botón 1');
    // Intento detener la propagación del evento
    event.stopPropagation();
});

document.getElementById('boton2').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Clic en el Botón 2');
    // Intento detener la propagación del evento
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#contenedor{
  background-color:red;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Problema con eventos en JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">
    <button id="boton1">Botón 1</button>
    <button id="boton2">Botón 2</button>
    <!-- Más elementos hijos aquí -->
</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo lo veo bien en chrome, si pincho en el botón no veo el click en el contenedor. Qué navegador usas? Otra opción es añadir un `return false;`  al final del handler del click

Comment: cual es el error?
dado que no veo error en el comportamiento de tu codigo!